# Varnish Cache on Virtualmin and phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, varnish, varnish-vcl, virtualmin, varnish-4

I have installed Varnish Cache ver.4 on CentOS6 machine running Virtualmin.  There is no problem accessing websites set via Virtualmin but cannot get to /phpmyadmin for each virtual host.

Have added

```
if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
return (pass);
}
```

to `sub vcl_recv` without any luck.

Varnish configuration is a default one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html#hit-for-pass-objects-are-created-using-beresp-uncacheable